# create statement for trigger not working + delimiter error + mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

Following create statement for trigger not working:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `bid_AFTER_INSERT` ;
DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `blah`.`bid_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `bid` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","created_date",null,new.created_date,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","created_id",null,new.created_id,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","name",null,new.name,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","first_delivery",null,new.first_delivery,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","email",null,new.email,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","final_delivery",null,new.final_delivery,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","master_bid_id",null,new.final_delivery,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","partner_id",null,new.partner_id,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","orders_id",null,new.orders_id,new.id);
END

  |
DELIMITER ;
```

Getting following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: I would remove the blank line after the delimiter and later after the END

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insightbasev2`.`bid_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `bid` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","created_date",null,new.created_date,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","created_id",null,new.created_id,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","name",null,new.name,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","first_delivery",null,new.first_delivery,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","email",null,new.email,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","final_delivery",null,new.final_delivery,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","master_bid_id",null,new.final_delivery,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","partner_id",null,new.partner_id,new.id);
        call sp_internal_bid_history_updation_on_bid_insert("bid","orders_id",null,new.orders_id,new.id);
END
DELIMETER ;
```

Just try above code.

I had tried it and it's working fine for me.

Comment: you forgot to set back the delimiter to default. End your code snippet with this line `DELIMITER ;` Someone copying this could end up in deep trouble.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher call to **`procedure`** is not working or this create **`trigger`** statement is not working??